# Problem with importing RUSBoostClassifier from imblearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, python-import, imblearn

I have gotten stuck with importing RUSBoostClassifier following [this example](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.RUSBoostClassifier.html#imblearn.ensemble.RUSBoostClassifier)

```
from imblearn.ensemble import RUSBoostClassifier
```

I receive the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d0ff5157a81a> in <module>
----> 1 from imblearn.ensemble import RUSBoostClassifier
  2 from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
  3 
  4 X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=3,
  5                            n_informative=4, weights=[0.2, 0.3, 0.5],

ImportError: cannot import name 'RUSBoostClassifier'
```

I do not understand why! I can easily use other modules from imblearn such as

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
```

or

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

I use Jupyter notebook, the Python version is 3.6.6. I have updated sklearn package and reinstall imblearn package following this [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/imbalanced-learn).

Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem? Or have an idea to use directly this class (source code) in a code?

Comment: Please post the complete error trace. Are you sure your Jupyter notebook runs in the same anaconda environment where `imblearn` is installed?

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for the reply! About your question: I have only one anaconda environment. For this reason, I guess I run the Jupyter Notebook in the same anaconda environment where imblearn was installed. About the full Error message, I edited the post. You can see it there.

Comment: Still not quite sure about the environments; can you run a `!pip list` command in Jupyter and see if `imblearn` is indeed included in the installed packages?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. With your hint I saw that the version of the imblearn was 0.3.0 (although I have reinstalled the imblearn already!). New modules are supported in the latest version of imblearn (version 0.4.3). This time I removed completely the imblearn pakage and installed it again via Anaconda. After the installation I could successfully use all the modules in imblearn.

Comment: Cool! I suggest you post this as an answer, to help others in the future that may face similar situations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of `imblearn` package. New modules of imblearn such as `RUSBoostClassifier` or `BalancedRandomForestClassifier` are supported in version 0.4.3. The version of `imblearn` package can be checked with `!pip list` (thanks to @desertnaut). If you are using an old version, remove it completely (reinstalling the imblearn was not actually helpful for me). After that follow [this instruction](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/imbalanced-learn) and install it in agin. In this case the latest version of imblearn will be added to your anaconda environment.